# How to find which view is resolved from url in presence of decorators

Tags: python, django, django-urls

For debugging purposes, I'd like a quick way (e.g. in manage.py shell) of looking up which view that will be called as a result of a specific URL being requested.
I know this is what django.core.urlresolvers.resolve does, but when having a decorator on the view function it will return that decorator.
Example:

```
>>>django.core.urlresolvers.resolve('/edit_settings/'))
(Allow, (), {})
```

...where Allow is the decorator, not the view it's decorating.

How can I find the view without manually inspecting the urls.py files?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't my area of expertise, but it might help.

You might be able to introspect `Allow` to find out which object it's decorating.

```
>>>from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
>>>func, args, kwargs=resolve('/edit_settings/')
>>>func
Allow
```

You could try

```
>>>func.func_name
```

but it might not return the view function you want.

Here's what I found when I was experimenting with basic decorator functions:

```
>>>def decorator(func):
...    def wrapped(*args,**kwargs):
...        return func(*args,**kwargs)
...    wrapped.__doc__ = "Wrapped function: %s" %func.__name__
...    return wrapped

>>>def add(a,b):
...    return(a,b)

>>>decorated_add=decorator(add)
```

In this case, when I tried `decorated_add.func_name` it returned `wrapped`. However, I wanted to find a way to return `add`. Because I added the doc string to `wrapped`, I could determine the original function name:

```
>>>decorated_add.func_name
wrapped
>>>decorated_add.__doc__
'Wrapped function: add'
```

Hopefully, you can find out how to introspect `Allow` to find out the name of the view function, possibly by modifying the decorator function.